# Can I call Python library using JNI?

Tags: java, python, c++, java-native-interface

I know there is jython solution, but jython can not load wtxl and rdxl; it can only load limited pip libraries. So I want to write JNI to do it.

The main procedure is as follows:
Java <-> JNI <-> C/C++ Python Interface <-> Local Python environment <-> my html2excel python libraries

The problem is that it fails to import the html2excel library. I use C/C++ code as this:

```cpp
int to_excel(const std::string & htmlfile)
{
    Py_Initialize();
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('/home/allen/python')");
    PyObject *html2excelModule = PyImport_ImportModule("html2excel");
    if (!html2excelModule )
    {
        std::cerr << "Error: open python html2excel failed" << std::endl;
        Py_Finalize();
        return -1;
    }
    ...
}
```

The above program tells gives me this error

> ImportError: No module named html2excel

html2excel.py is located in /home/allen/python. It is ok when running from shell.

```
$python
>>>import sys
>>>sys.path.append('/home/allen/python')
>>>import html2excel
```

Why does my JNI library fail to import the existing html2excel module? Thank you in advance!

Comment: you should check the return codes of the previous functions called

Comment: The previous functions called successfully, all returned 0.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows that rlm_python:EXCEPT:: /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so: undefined symbol: _Py_ZeroStruct

libpython2.7.so should be manually loaded by use of dlopen in JNI implementation.

The detailed solution is given https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/pull/415.

Comment: You should improve your answer by adding relevant information from the link.